# Node Express Server Cannot GET "/"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am writing some code for my node server and everything is working fine locally. However, when I deploy it, I get the infamous "Cannot GET /" 404 error. All of the other routes which I have written work successfully (Both locally and in the cloud).

I have included the code below. I've checked my environment variables and all of them properly align. If any of you have any theories concerning the cause of this, it would be much appreciated.

```js
//Use this route to make the entire app secure.  This forces login for any path in the entire app.
  app.use('/', passport.authenticate('main', {
    noredirect: false //Don't redirect a user to the authentication page, just show an error
  }),
    express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public'))
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify @aprouja1

```
// You usually want to declare statics separately for code organisation
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')))

app.use('/', 
  passport.authenticate('main', {
    noredirect: false
  }), 
  function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html')
  }
);
```

For an index page apart of an application of any complexity, it's probably better to use a rendering engine, e.g. pug.

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); // Not required. Set by default. Being explicit.
app.engine('pug', require('pug').__express); // Not required. Automatically loaded by express. Again, being explicit.
app.set('view engine', 'pug'); // Required, see: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

app.use('/', 
  passport.authenticate('main', {
    noredirect: false
  }), 
  function(req, res) {
    res.render('index') // Renders `/views/index.pug`
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are serving any files to the user when they navigate to that route. Do you have an index.html or some other file? If so, you can use this inside your app.use function:

```
res.sendFile('index.html')
```